ZFS-pool without striping to be used within VM-images?
I'm going to setup a VM, starting with two disks, one for / and one for the data using a ZFS-pool. Don't want to create VM disks too large, even in case of dynamically growing ones, and prefer chunks of e.g. 250 GiB per disk. Makes backup, file handling etc. easier in various cases in my opinion. So at some point the VM might end up having 4 virtual disks instead of one large one with 1 TiB. The only downside of that approach is that ZFS thinks to have 4 individual disks and spans I/O and data over all of those 4 disks.
Is there any way to prevent that and make ZFS use a JBOD-like approach? So that while it does use all of the disks, e.g. it simply writes from the start to the back in a linear way?
I'm aware of possible workarounds like LVM within the VM, but that's unnecessary difficult. I can easily live with the downside of the ZFS-setup and did so in the past, wasn't that much of a problem even when the virtual disks were backed by HDDs only.
I didn't find anything and was wondering if I missed something or it's simply not supported.

AFAIK ZFS do not support concatenated pool. Maybe you can reconsider about LVM

To the close voters (and their comments deleting friend :-)): What exactly is doesn’t meet a Server Fault guideline. in my question?

Yeah, you can do whatever you want, but just 'cause you can doesn’t mean you should. If you go that route, you're messing with your data integrity by skipping redundancy. What I'd do? I'd toss in at least one more drive, set up RAIDZ, and maybe throw in a cheap NVMe for ZIL/SLOG. That way, you're giving ZFS a chance to show off all its important features.

Someone deleted many of my comments for strange reasons... :-D This answer suggests that a linear setup is possible, without explaining anything about how. So how is that linear setup I was asking about possible? Additionally, data integrity is maintained by the storage layer outside the VM, there's no need to take care of it inside the VM additionally. NVMe and ZIL/SLOG have nothing to do with my question at all and are of course not handled at the VM-level, but at the outer storage again.

This sounds like a bad idea. This is counter to the purpose of ZFS, so a linear allocation isn't something that ZFS support.
I'm curious what problem you're interested in solving with this design.

In my setup there's simply no benefit in splitting writes across multiple devices, because all files are backed by the same storage device in the end, a single HDD in the worst case. OTOH, with linear writes, only those backing virtual disks would be changed which are really needed to store some data. This e.g. improves backups based on RSYNC, which in the best case would be able to skip whole VM disks based on last written timestamps.

ZFS parallels writes, so for sure you’ll get better write performance even without ZIL.

@BaronSamedi1958, in above situation parallels writes will have negative impact on the performance because VM platform will allocate new disks somewhere and the disk heads will jump back and forth

ZFS doesn’t work the way you think it works. In a nutshell: Writes hit the log initially, so there’s no “I/O blender” effect you’re describing here.

Unless explicitly setup otherwise, there's one small ZIL per disk, which are multiple in my use-case. So yes, even with the log you have ZFS distirbuting writes to what it thinks are multiple disks, which aren't physically. Additionally, that small ZIL is only used for SYNC writes, which are not the default in my use-case.
When synchronous writes are requested, the ZIL is the short-term place on disk where the data lands[...] By default, the short-term ZIL storage exists on the same hard disks[...]
https://www.truenas.com/docs/references/zilandslog/
